# function which returns as hstore datatype in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, hstore

"hstoredata" is a variable of type hstore which contains key value pairs.

i.e. for ex: "hstoredata" variable contains the key value pairs `'"ed"=>"1", "id"=>"1", "age"=>"27"'`.

If "hstoredata" variable is passed to the function i.e `select sampletest(hstoredata)`, function is returning as null.

```
-- Function: sampletest(hstore)

-- DROP FUNCTION sampletest(hstore)

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION sampletest(hstoredata hstore)    
RETURNS SETOF void AS    
$BODY$     
DECLARE   
newhstoredata hstore;    
BEGIN    
    newhstoredata := samplehstore(hstoredata);    
    RAISE NOTICE 'newhstoredata: %', newhstoredata;    
END;    
$BODY$    
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE    
  COST 100    
  ROWS 1000;    
ALTER FUNCTION sampletest(hstore)   
  OWNER TO postgres;
```

Below is the program for function `samplehstore(hstore)`

```
-- Function: samplehstore(hstore)

-- DROP FUNCTION samplehstore(hstore)

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION samplehstore(hstoredata hstore)    
RETURNS SETOF void AS    
$BODY$     
BEGIN       
    RAISE NOTICE 'hstoredata: %', hstoredata;    
END;   
$BODY$    
LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE    
COST 100
ROWS 1000;
ALTER FUNCTION samplehstore(hstore)
OWNER TO postgres;
```

Comment: And what is the question/problem ?

Answer (score 1):

It's unclear what you're asking precisely, but based on the title, I assume you'd like your function to return something.

If so, the issue here is that you're declaring your function as returning `setof void`.

Declare it as returning whatever it should, and use `return ...` or `return query ...`, depending on what you actually need.